# MongoDB\Collection::mapReduce()を実行の問題

Tags: mongodb

最近MongoDBの環境に関して結構悩んでおります。
環境：　
・MongoDB Server 3.2.0
　(*Microsoft AzureのCosmosDBにMongoDB API利用でデータベースを作成した)
・mongo_php_driver 1.4.3
・mongo_php_library 1.3.2
・PHP 5.6.35
目的：
・MongoDB\Collection::mapReduce()を実行したい。
問題：
・exception 'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Command is not supported' (MongoDB\Driver\Server->executeReadCommand)

Answer (score 0):

[リリースノート](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/tag/1.4.0)を見ると、`executeReadCommand`は1.4.0から追加されているようなので、実際にはmongo_php_driver 1.4.0より前のバージョンが使用されているということはないですかね？
`composer.json`を見直すことで解決しないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうごさいます。composer.jsonファイル構成を確認したところ下記の通りなのでバージョンが大丈夫そうだけど。。。    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5",
        "ext-hash": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-mongodb": "^1.4.0"
    }

Comment: ローカルにDBサーバーを立ち上げて試したらmapReduce()が問題なく実行出来てます。・MongoDB Server 3.6.3
・mongo_php_driver 1.4.3
・mongo_php_library 1.3.2
・PHP 5.6.34（*）

Comment: Azure Cosmos DBが`mapReduce`をサポートしていないのかも。

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#database-commands

Comment: そうでした。何とか納得出来るようになりました。ご協力ありがとうございます。＾～＾